# Getting empty array when using get in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a database connection but still getting the message "No product found" Please tell me what the error is, also try to answer in the simplest way possible, thank you

the code is

```
const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SearchApp")
const Ad = require("./database/Ad");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, resp) => {
  let ads = await Ad.find();
  if(ads.length>0){

  resp.send(ads);
  }else{
    resp.send("No Product Found")
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```
Ad.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const adSch = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  headline: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Ads", adSch);
```

Comment: have you passed any data in your model yet ?

Comment: what is `Ad`? where it comes from?

Comment: @zb22 Ad is coming from the a separate file, Ad.js where I have added schema and model, check below

Comment: @RahulMohanty I don't need to, I just want to read the api

Comment: Looks like you don't have any data in there yet, so your output is expected.

Comment: @Lissy93 I have the data, it is there in the collection of my database

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. In fact I ran your code in my machine and got some data/output.

I have added console.log to debug

```
const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SearchApp")
const Ad = require("./ad-schema");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, resp) => {
let ads = await Ad.find();
console.log("ads", ads);
if (ads.length > 0) {
    console.log("if hitting");
    resp.send(ads);
} else {
    console.log("else hitting");
    resp.send("No Product Found")
}
});

app.listen(3000);
```

[image: Output]

[image: console.log]